# Getting a list of all fields name in a table

Tags: sql, sybase

Anticipating that I don't know much of SQL: I have a table named "MY_TABLE" and I would like to retrieve all the names of fields contained into this table into a list. 
Walking through the web I have found this code snippet:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
```

That looks pretty straight-forward to me, and what I expect is a list such as:

```
FIELD_1
FIELD_2
...
FIELD_n
```

but when I try to execute this query into my query analyzer I get the following error message:

```
>[Error] Script lines: 1-3 --------------------------
information_schema.columns not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check   whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).
Msg: 208, Level: 16, State: 1
Server: JUMBO, Line: 1
```

Any help?

Comment: What version of Sybase are you using?

Comment: I guess is the 12.5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it might depend on which version of Sybase you are using but according to the Sybase documentation for ASE 12.5 the system tables you probably want to use is:

[syscolumns](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc36271_36272_36273_36274_1250/html/refman/X14340.htm) and [sysobjects](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc36271_36272_36273_36274_1250/html/refman/X14933.htm).

> sysobjects contains one row for each table, view, stored procedure,
>   extended stored procedure, log, rule, default, trigger, check
>   constraint, referential constraint, and (in tempdb only) temporary
>   object.
>
> syscolumns contains one row for every column in every table and view,
>   and a row for each parameter in a procedure.

The query you want is probably this:

```
select c.name from syscolumns c
inner join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id
where o.name = 'MY_TABLE'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly. I was able to compose pretty much the same query starting from this [reference](http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server/sys.columns_Getting_a_List_of_Columns_in_a_Table.html) after your 'sys.columns' suggestion, but your code gives me just what I need. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. You can see in the error itself that the schema as an alias for column which you are using in query is wrong. Please check you schema name again. And other possibility is check you column name properly and the important thing is check permission for schema whether you have permission to execute your query in that schema or not (R/W/X).